# Python "how many elements have"

Tags: python

I have some data, for example:

```
input=[['1', '7', 'U1'], ['1.5', '8', 'U1'], ['2', '5.5', 'U1'], ['2', '9', 'U1'], ['2.5', '6.5', 'U1'], ['2.5', '8', 'U1'], ['2.5', '10', 'U2'], ['3', '4.5', 'U2'], ['3', '9', 'U2'], ['3.5', '5.5', 'U2']]
```

How can I get numbers of how many U1 and U2 data is in all my data? **This U1 and U2 is always on last place of every row**, but **has various name**(so it must first read name....)!!!. I want to get for this example:

```
U1: 6
U2: 4
```

Comment: I assume you mean `U2: 4` since there are four of them in your example, not three.

Comment: yes, in this example 4, sorry my mistake...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I modified the index from `2` to `-1` to reflect your requirement of 'last element on every row' in case each row has a different number of elements.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for record in input:
    d[record[-1]] += 1
print d
```

Comment: @thaking: No, your input is `input` just like in your example. `d` is a dictionary that accumulates the line-by-line counts of how many records have each string.

Comment: Hmmm, but how can I now call this values, for example if I want to use this number, I try  d[0,1...]...but not working

Comment: @thaking: `print d["U1"]` or `for k in d: print(k)` or `for k, v in d.items(): print(k, v)` or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using a *list comprehension*:

```
num_u1 = len([x for x in input if x[2] == "U1"])
num_u2 = len([x for x in input if x[2] == "U2"])
```

There are other ways to do this that are less repetitive if you have more than two things you're looking for.

Comment: Yes I know for that, but as I write U1 and U2 is just in this example, sometimes I have many other "strings" and different name's, but always on last place of each row

Comment: @thaking:  Then please clarify your requirements.

Comment: `sum(1 for ...)` is better, or if you prefer `sum(x[2] == "U1" for ...)`

Answer (score 3):

For python2.7+

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(map(itemgetter(-1), input))
Counter({'U1': 6, 'U2': 4})
```

Using `input` as a variable name is a bad idea because it shadows the builtin `input()`